Comedy name? Jew and neo-nazi hook up
It's a teen comedy. A bunch of guys traveled somewhere and were trying to score with some chicks.
This is what I remember:
1) This guy who is Jewish and a bit of a nerd fells for a hot German girl (I think she was an exchange student). But soon he starts to suspect that she is a Neo-Nazi. She reads "Mein Kampf" and even highlights it with a marker. She even showed him a picture of her grandpa from Argentina (an old Hitler with white hair). The two end up having sex and when confronted by his friends the guy responds: "She is a Nazi and I hate being a Jew. It's perfect!"
2) He injured his arms and had to wear casts. He mistook Viagra for painkillers and then tried to please himself with a vacuum cleaner.
I'm not sure about the second one. It could be a different movie. 

It's Bachelor Party 2: The Last Temptation from 2008. The hot Nazi highlighting Mein Kampf, the Jewish guy lusting after her and saying it's perfect because he hates himself, the double arm cast & Viagra... It's all there. Here's the trailer.
